# Android: SQLiteDatabase InsertWithOnConflict API 7

Tags: android, sqlite, on-duplicate-key

Is there some easy way (easier than building up your own query), how to include

```
SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict();
```

in Android API since v7 ?

As far as I know, this is included in API since v8. Some kind of compatibility library, would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are welcome to copy [the implementation of that method from the open source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java) and use it as you see fit. At the time of this writing, it is on lines 1667 through 1725.

Comment: so make own SQLiteDatabase subclass, fill in missing methods and enums, and use for compatibility purpose? ok then :-)

Comment: Did you get this to work? There were quite a few private members required to be added from internal Android classes, such as the constructor for SqlStatement